# How to highlight all cells in a column (Google spreadsheet) that DON'T start from "QA-" (case sensitive)?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huJzW.png)

How to highlight ALL cells in a "D" column that DON'T start from "QA-"
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you looking for a script to do this for you?

Comment: Yes. I need a formula in order to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this formula:

**=IF(EXACT("QA-",LEFT(D:D, 3))=FALSE,TRUE)**

I hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks a lot! This formula works fine. This definitely what I needed!